# I need to use setter in DAO methods?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

> DAO method 
>    **I can't able to use setter method  here**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ArrayList<shopModel> viewShopinfo() {
        ArrayList<shopModel> list = new ArrayList<shopModel>();
        shopModel sh=new shopModel();
        try 
        {           
           session.beginTransaction();          
           String viewQuery="SELECT * FROM shop_information";           
           query = session.createSQLQuery(viewQuery);
           query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);//To execute A Select Query
           query.setParameter("storeName", sh.getStoreName());
           query.setParameter("ownername", sh.getOwnername());
           list = (ArrayList<shopModel>) query.list();
           System.out.println("List values : "+ query.setParameter("ownername", sh.getOwnername()));
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Class :shopDao Method viewShopinfo Exception :"
                    + ex);
        } 
        finally 
        {
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

JSP page

```
<%                      
                 shopService shp=new shopService();
                ArrayList<shopModel> list=shp.viewShopinfo();
                System.out.println("welcome list : " + list.size());                
                 for (int index=0; index<list.size(); index++)  
                 {
                     System.out.println("welcome index : " + list.size());
                       shopModel shop = list.get(index);                        
                     System.out.println("welcome Store : " + shop.getStoreName()); 
                  %>
```

Error page

> .Class :shopDao Method viewShopinfo Exception
>   :org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named
>   parameter [storeName].

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: values are not stored in model method...i required to display all the values   in design jsp page but it showing error ..i am using hibernate database connection

Answer (score 1):

Where is the parameter `store name` in your `query`?
Your query must be something like this

```
     String viewQuery="SELECT * FROM shop_information 
where storeName=:storeName and ownerName=:ownerName";
```

Comment: values are not stored in model method...i required to display all the values in design jsp page.

Comment: @AjithCsE can you post your model?

Comment: @Entity
@Table(name = "shop_information")
public class shopModel 
{
@Column(name = "sno") 
 private String  sno;
@Column(name = "storeName")
 private String  storeName;
@Column(name = "ownername")
 private String  ownername;

public String getStoreName() { 
 return storeName;
}
public void setStoreName(String storeName) { 
 this.storeName = storeName;
}

public String getOwnername() {
 return ownername;
}

public void setOwnername(String ownername) { 
 this.ownername = ownername;
}
}